# Flagging changed items in DataServiceCollection (OData)

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services

I've got a Silverlight application that has created a master/detail view of data coming from an OData feed (my first app). When I make changes to an item in the detail view, they are showing up just fine in the master, but the user has no indication on what has changed (including adds & deletes).

For some reason I can't find a property that indicates that the collection has changed. There is a CollectionChanged event, but that's only for items it seems, not for their properties.

Is it possible to easily determine what items have changed in a DataServiceCollection and easily show which ones those are? I expect I could build something that walked through the collection, but that's not idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is INotifyPropertyChanged event, that gets fired when the properties are changed. Does that help?

Thanks
Pratik